# django-cms how to change the wisiwyg editor to use aloha editor?

Tags: django-cms, aloha-editor

I wonder if I can change the wisiwyg of the text plugin of django-cms to be the aloha editor ... I search but I couldn't found how to do this .... The other option is to create a custom plugin text which use aloha editor but doing this I don't know how to define the in-line editing of this plugin.
Any help?

Comment: What do you mean by 'in-line editing of this plugin'?

Answer (score 0):

You might try using a pre-built django integration package for aloha: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-aloha-edit,

Then use the HTMLField, or simply use the AlohaWidget and specify the backend. The HTMLField does important sanitation, but if you're only editing from the backend with trusted users this is not necessary, and you can just override the widget in the form.